# How to check if string is a valid inquiry

Tags: javascript, string, string-parsing

I need to ensure that certain strings are valid questions. I am thinking of how to write this myself, but without being pretty limiting it is actually a fairly complex bit of analysis, and I'm sure it must have been done many times before.

I'm not just talking about starting with an interrogatory word and ending with a question mark. For example I would like all these to pass:

1. Is the grand canyon large?
2. I know canyons are usually pretty big, but is the grand canyon large?
3. I was thinking earlier, is the grand canyon a large canyon?

I would love to get hold of an existing js lib (or port something) that does this for me. I've been looking around for a while but have found nothing.

- P.S. I had to use the word 'inquiry' in the title as the word 'question' is banned.

Comment: This extends beyond the language you're using and into linguistic semantic parsing, a complex and (highly sough after) professional speciality. I'd be surprised if a JS library exists for this, most natural language processing code is proprietary and owned by the big guys (Google, MS, Amazon etc).

Comment: [compromise.js](http://compromise.cool/) is a JS NLP engine, it even has a `.questions()` subset.  Of course its not a magical fix-all so YMMV.

Comment: @Jay Gould - Hey - thanks for getting back. Yes I agree, but I though it may be common enough that there might be something, as there are for detecting potentially offensive language. Though these often use a less semantic / brute force approach.

Comment: @Alex K - Oh wow - at a glance this looks exactly the sort of thing I'm looking for! Thanks, I'll investigate now!

Comment: Google Cloud has an NLP API as well, paid for I think.

Comment: @Alex K - Oooh that is interesting too, just checked it out. I'm probably going to be releasing on GCloude so may come in handy.  For the time being though, I just plugged in compromise.js and it did exactly what I needed! For a second there my faith in npm was momentarily shaken!! Thanks mate!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alex K in the comments under my question gave me the exact answer I needed.

[compromise.js](http://compromise.cool/)

Awesome! :-)

**Edit:**

As requested, here is a working example.

In your terminal, with [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm) installed, type the following:

```
npm install compromise
```

Now to test if a string (myString) contains a question you would use the following:

```
var nlp = require('compromise');
var containsQuestion = nlp(myString).questions().data().length === 1;
```

(In the above case, multiple questions also results in a negative result)